# Unit Testing While Using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, entity-framework-4, nunit, mstest

I have a web application that has been created using MVC 3 and Entity Framework. I would like to start using unit testing, but so far I have not been able to run any unit tests due to the way the system talks to the database.

I have a BaseController, which defines a DataContext as a variable:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    public Models.MyEntities DataContext = new Models.MyEntities();
```

Each controller then inherits the BaseController, thereby making the DataContext variable available to all controllers without redefining it:

```
public class ErrorController : BaseController
{
```

When I run a unit test, I receive an error about the object reference not being set to an instance of an object, each time referring to the line where I access DataContext.

Most references to unit testing say you should be abstracting your database layer, and using fake data for testing. This seems counter-intuitive to me, but that is a different discussion.

My question is - is it possible to use unit testing with the system configured the way it is? I am open to using any testing framework available, either MSTest, NUnit / XUnit etc.

Comment: Take a look at [this aricle](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84). It describes how to abstract your LINQ enabled O/RM tool behind an abstraction to allow unit testing.

Comment: Steven, I have seen your blog post in response to similar questions, it's a great tutorial on how to achieve this, but I am not sure it is what I want to do. Besides, I am using an EDMX file to generate the entities, rather than POCO. Is it still possible to abstract this?

Comment: Call me old fashion, but I've never used POCO entities and the article was written with and tested with generated entities. The testability will never be as great as when using POCOs, but I found it to be more than sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Maybe you could follow this [approach](http://blogofrab.blogspot.com/2010/08/maintenance-free-mocking-for-unit.html) ?

Comment: Is your DataContext connected to the database during unit testing? I had a similar problem with EF Code First because the connection string, which is stored in Web.config, was not available during unit testing.

Comment: Juraj - I initially got an error about the missing connection string, so I copied the web.config and renamed it to app.config, after which the error ceased, to be replaced with the one listed above. I am not sure if it is connected, however.